# Button onClick event inside react datatable doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have written a render function and have provided the buttons for edit and delete in each row of the datatable. onclick event is using react redux action method. but when I click edit/delete button I get 
'Cannot read property 'props' of undefined' error

```
import { DataTable } from 'react-data-components';
    <DataTable
      keys="title"
       columns={[
       { title: 'Report Name', prop: 'title'},
       { title: 'Author', prop: 'username'},
       { title: 'date Created', prop: 'datecreated'},
       { title: 'Date Modified', prop: 'datelastmodified'},
       {title:'Actions', render:function(val, row) {
          return React.createElement( "div", null,
           React.createElement( "button", {className:"btn", onClick:(e)=>this.props.EditReport(row.reportid)}, 'Edit'),
           React.createElement( "button", {className:"btn", onClick:(e)=>this.props.DeleteReport(row.reportid)}, 'Delete')
       )
     }
     }
  ]}
  initialData={this.props.savedReportList.data}
  initialPageLength={5}
 />

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      EditReport: (reportID) => dispatch(EditReport(reportID)),
      DeleteReport: (reportID) => dispatch(DeleteReport(reportID))
  }
}
```

Comment: is this your full code ? Did you use class base or function base component ?

Comment: Additionally have you used function `connect` from react-redux?

Comment: Yes I have imported connect as well as redux action method.                                       import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {EditReport,DeleteReport} from './Actions';

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `this` out of scope. What are you trying to achieve? We can take it from there.

Comment: if I remove Action column from my above code dataTable displays the data even when initialData uses data from 'this' scope. Then why only in render function the 'this' goes out of scope